# Html5 video plays only for some times

Tags: javascript, html, oop, video

Before I go into the problem I would like to say that this is the first time I'm trying to write javascript using OOP. So please bear with me and guide me if I doing anything wrong.

As title says I am using `HTML5` video to play videos in my application and here is the code which I wrote.

I have created an object `Screens` where I have a video tag.

```
var Screens = {
    getVideoScreen:function(){
        return "<div id=\"celebration\"><video id=\"myvideo1\" width=\"300px\"  ><source src=\"video/winning.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></div> "; 
    },
    getVideoElement:function() {
        return $("#celebration");
    }
};
```

This is an object where I actually control video.

```
var obj = Object.create(Screens);

obj.playVideo = (function() {
    var videoFile = "";
    var play = false;
    function start() {
        $("body").append(obj.getVideoScreen());
        document.getElementById("myvideo1").play();
        document.getElementById("myvideo1").addEventListener("ended",function(){
            end();  console.log("end");
        }, false);
    }
    function end() {
        obj.getVideoElement().remove(); 
    }
    return {
        startVideo:function(flag) {
            play = flag;
            if(play) {
                start();    
            }
            else {
                end();  
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

I have a button and on `click` it plays video,

```
 $("#start").click(function() {
        obj.playVideo.startVideo(true); 
 });
```

This works fine for around 5 to 10 times and later on it doesn't work. Doesn't work mean I get a white screen and video doesn't play. I inspected the page and video tag is there but doesn't play the video. I really don't have any idea about what is going wrong. I saw few posts and that didn't help. Looking ahead for a help....

EDIT :

I am using chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m. And I'm concerned only about this browser.

You can see [this](http://purple-works.com/vinay/so.html) page.

Comment: Do you have a sample page that we could look at? Also which browser(s) is it not working in?

Comment: @IanDevlin sure I'll make one now. I'll edit my post

Comment: Worked fine for me, more than 10 times. No issues at all. I was even able to have two videos playing at the same time. Also why are you using the XHTML DOCTYPE?

Comment: @IanDevlin I just removed it. After your comment I checked it through link. Its working fine here as well(from server). This happens when I run it locally.

Comment: @IanDevlin Actually the video has 1920x1080 resolution. I zoomed it out for more than 75% of the actual size. Now when I run it in the monitor which suits the resolution it works fine. But still I'm not sure.